# @html.dropdown onchange event MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a View with a dropdownlist.  I would like to select a value from the dropdownlist and depending on that value pull into the View a form related to that selection.

Looks like this:

[image]

I would like the form to appear below this ddlist and if the user changes the value in the ddlist, it would change the form.

Here's my "Add" View:

```
    <div id="matSelContainer">
    @Html.Action("SelectMaterial", "Materials", "Materials")
</div>
```

Here's the "SelectMaterial" View:

```
@model Procurement.Models.Material.MaterialType
@Html.Label("Select a Material Type:  ")
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.MaterialTypeList,
    new SelectList(Model.MaterialTypeList, "MaterialTypeId", "Name")
)
```

Here's my Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Add()
        {
            return View();
        }

 public ActionResult SelectMaterial()
        {           
            materialTypes.LoadMaterialTypes();
            return PartialView(materialTypes);
        }
```

I would like to have a separate View for each Material Type and just call that View based on the selection in the ddlist.

Can someone show me how to achieve this?

Would I add a separate @Html.Action to the "Add" View and then in the Controller have another action return a PartialView?

But how to connect this with the Onchange event?

> > Update<<
> >     Here's what is almost working for me:

"SelectMaterial" View:

```
@model Procurement.Models.Material.MaterialType
@Html.Label("Select a Material Type:  ")
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.MaterialTypeList,
    new SelectList(Model.MaterialTypeList, "MaterialTypeId", "Name"),
     new { @onchange="CallChangefunc(this.value)" })

<script>
    function CallChangefunc(val) {
        //alert("i am a " + obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text);
        //alert(obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text);
        window.location.href = "/Materials/MyMethod/" + val;
    }
</script>
```

In my Controller I have this ActionResult:

```
 public ActionResult MyMethod(string value)
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
```

My controller is getting called when I change selection but the value coming in is null.  I can see on the browser address bar that the expected selected value is being passed.  Why is it null in controller?  (I tried adding an [HttpPost] to ActionResult with no luck.)

Comment: Do you have a specific route for `MyMethod` that includes a `/{value}` placeholder? (by default you would need to use `public ActionResult MyMethod(string id)`

Comment: And you can avoid your script altogether by just using `<form>` with `FormMethod.Get` (but either way, do not handle the `.change event of your dropdownlist - its a bad ui (consider users who navigate options using the keyboard) - use a button instead